Log4j2 Migration getLoggers implementation vs log4j1
I'm in the process of upgrading to log4j2. Most of it seems to be working but I noticed when running up my application there is some varying behavior. Using log4j1, when I call:
Enumeration loggers = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers(); I will see 600+ loggers returned (this is expected). When using Log4j2, I replaced this call with LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false); Collection<Logger> allLoggers = context.getLoggers(); and it only returns around 180 loggers. Unfortunately I don't have access to my new properties file at the moment but it looks like a correct implementation of the prior version.
I will note that all the loggers are only coming from one of the loggers that I have declared in my properties (but all are following the same structure and use the same appender). Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks.
edit: I realized that the missing logs are all from third party libraries. I have setup my slf4j - log4j2 bridge but something appears to be wrong with that?
edit 2: here are logging deps from mvn dependency:tree :
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.24.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.24.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.24.0:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.24.0:compile



Check out Log4j 1 Backend Migration in our Migrating from Log4j 1 guide for a partial list of bridges you need to replace.
This sums up to:

Replacing slf4j-log4j12/reload4j with log4j-slf4j-impl (which you already did),
Upgrading commons-logging to version 1.3.0 or higher (which introduces an embedded JCL-to-Log4j 2 API bridge),
JBoss Logging API has support for Log4j 2 API since ages, but you might want to check that.
There was never a JUL-to-Log4j 1 bridge as far as I remember, but there is a JUL-to-Log4j 2 API bridge. See Installing JUL-to-Log4j bridge for more details. It might require a change in your application launch scripts or a static call to System.setProperty at the top of your main class.
System.Logger was introduced in the JRE after the last release of Log4j 1. You might want to add log4j-jpl to your application too. See Installing JPL-to-Log4j bridge for details.


Thanks so much - I'll try these out and let you know!

I tried adding jul, jpl, and jboss-logging with no luck. I do suspect this is a jboss related issue but I'm running out of troubleshooting ideas at this point. Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.

jboss-logging usage is rare (Hibernate is an exception), while JUL and JPL bridges are mostly optionals. The "missing" loggers are probably Commons Logging loggers (JCL). Note that there are two SLF4J bridges depending on the version of slf4j-api you are using: lof4j-slf4j-impl is for version 1.x, log4j-slf4j2-impl is for version 2.x.

I wasn't using commons-logging before though, is there a reason I would need to add it?

Can you add all your dependencies (including the transitive ones) that contain log4j, slf4j, jcl, jul or logging in their name to the question? commons-logging is a very popular transitive dependency. You don't need to add it as direct dependency but you can bump its version through some dependency management mechanism.

haha well I checked the tree again and I do see commons logging in there! So I will try bumping that version

Unfortunately adding commons-logging didn't work either.

commons-logging version 1.1.1 does not support Log4j 2 API. You need at least version 1.3.0.

Yeah, I added 1.3.4 and it did not work.

edit: I should also note that when deployed, the logs are not writing to the logfile I had set (which worked with log4j1). Could that make it clearly something more jboss related?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
